# Yahoo finance expanded financial tables scrape with R

Tags: r, rvest, yahoo-finance

I am trying to expand financial tables on yahoo finance with rvest.

```
url <- "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AEFES.IS/balance-sheet?p=AEFES.IS"
tic.nodes url.session %>% 
        html_elements(".fi-row") %>% 
        html_elements("[title]") %>% 
        html_text()

 [1] "Total Revenue"                                              "Cost of Revenue"                                           
 [3] "Gross Profit"                                               "Operating Expense"                                         
 [5] "Operating Income"                                           "Net Non Operating Interest Income Expense"                 
 [7] "Pretax Income"                                              "Tax Provision"                                             
 [9] "Net Income Common Stockholders"                             "Diluted NI Available to Com Stockholders"                  
[11] "Basic EPS"                                                  "Diluted EPS"                                               
[13] "Basic Average Shares"                                       "Diluted Average Shares"                                    
[15] "Total Operating Income as Reported"                         "Rent Expense Supplemental"                                 
[17] "Total Expenses"                                             "Net Income from Continuing & Discontinued Operation"       
[19] "Normalized Income"                                          "Interest Income"                                           
[21] "Interest Expense"                                           "Net Interest Income"                                       
[23] "EBIT"                                                       "EBITDA"                                                    
[25] "Reconciled Cost of Revenue"                                 "Reconciled Depreciation"                                   
[27] "Net Income from Continuing Operation Net Minority Interest" "Total Unusual Items Excluding Goodwill"                    
[29] "Total Unusual Items"                                        "Normalized EBITDA"                                         
[31] "Tax Rate for Calcs"                                         "Tax Effect of Unusual Items"
```

However, the expanded table has 47 rows. On HTML code all lines start with fi-row but on the code, it won't take the under divisions.[expand income statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XUVm.png) can you guys help me please?